# Displaying a loaded texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to make a game, it's 2D and has a moving player. I haven't worked with textures before and getting to display this texture correctly is very frustrating for me.

Current Output: http://puu.sh/7hTEL/64ac1529b1.jpg

My Image: http://puu.sh/7hUlM/3be59d6497.jpg

I just want that image to repeat itself (both x and y) over the background of the screen. at the moment I just have a fixed height / width for the game. It focuses on the player and the player is always moving in the x direction!

I have stripped down as most I can:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "snake.h"

#include <GL\glut.h>

GLuint texture = 0;
snake_t* snake = new snake_t();

GLuint LoadTexture( const char * filename, int width, int height )
{
    GLuint texture;
    unsigned char * data;
    FILE * file;

    //The following code will read in our RAW file
    file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
    data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );
    fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
    fclose( file );

    glGenTextures( 1, &texture ); 
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture ); 
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE ); 


    //even better quality, but this will do for now.
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );


    //to the edge of our shape. 
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

    //Generate the texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    free( data ); //free the texture
    return texture; //return whether it was successful
}

void display( void )
{
    //set view of scene
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluOrtho2D( snake->x - start_x, (640 + snake->x) - start_x, 0.0, 480);

    //gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 0, 480);



    //draw texture on background
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture ); 

    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i(0,0); glVertex2f(snake->x - start_x, 480);
        glTexCoord2i(1,0); glVertex2f(640 + snake->x, 480);
        glTexCoord2i(1,1); glVertex2f(640 + snake->x, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(0,1); glVertex2f(snake->x - start_x, 0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();


    glColor3f( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    //render scene
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
   glutInit( &argc, argv );
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize (640, 480);
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow( "Slidey Snake" );
   glutDisplayFunc( display );
   //glutKeyboardFunc( buttonmap );
   //glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

   //init();
   //Timer(0);

   texture = LoadTexture("sky.png", 256, 256);

   glutMainLoop();

   return 0;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit, I laughed at this one :) You are using the raw **PNG** file data as being RGB pixel data. That is not correct. PNG files are compressed. You first need to decode them before you feed them into OpenGL. Slick2D is a library that does the job nicely.

Comment: completely forgot about that one. haha what are some raw image formats? bmp?

Comment: None. They all must specify at least width and height (unless the amount of pixels is the product of two primes :P ). Just take a look at slick.